# HAProxy - Cancel request

Tags: haproxy

We have a HAProxy in front of all our applications. It redirects all http traffic to https, manages ssl and does some rewriting do split requests to `/*` and `/api/*` to different backends.

One backend handles requests which can run up to 3 min. This request can be fired very often but also will be canceled often like this:
[image]

To reduce load, the backend server handles canceled requests and stops the work. But with the HAProxy between, my backend server does not recognize canceled requests. I thought `option abortonclose` will be the option i'm looking for, but it does not work as expected.

Here is a snippet of our config

```
...

defaults
    log      global
    mode     http
    option   redispatch
    option   tcplog
    option   dontlognull
    option   abortonclose
    retries  3
    timeout  http-request 10s
    timeout  queue 1m
    timeout  connect 10s
    timeout  client 1m
    timeout  server 1m
    timeout  check 10s

...

listen redirect-http-proxy
    bind xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
    acl http ssl_fc,not
    http-request redirect scheme https if http

frontend proxy_ssl
    bind xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/xxx.pem
    option tcpka
    #map-file
    use_backend %[base,lower,map_beg(/etc/haproxy/xxx.map,bk_default)]

...

backend my-backend-name
     balance roundrobin
     option  tcp-check
     server my-server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12345/api check port 12345 inter 5000 rise 2 fall 5
```

Comment: Don't think stackoverflow is the best place to ask for this topic as its is not quite programming-related. Not quite sure which other SE site would be more appropriate though, as I don't think either superuser or networkengineering.SE really fit your question.

Comment: I would suggest [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).  When posting there, please include HAProxy log entries for these canceled requests.  You may also want to familiarize yourself with the codes explained in the documentation section called [Session state at disconnection](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#8.5).

Comment: What do canceled requests look like ?
Can you show HAProxy logs showing canceled request ?

Comment: I had the same problem just a few days ago, I thought HAProxy was canceling my request but that wasn't the problem. The problem was in someplace of Angular code. You can try disable HAProxy and look at see if the problem come from there.